# How exactly does a program load a DLL at runtime? (Also wondering a bit about the PE file format since it's related)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, portable-executable

I'm a little confused. As far as I understand it (although I might be mistaken), in order for a program to access a DLL and its functions it needs to load the DLL into the program itself. Does that mean that it literally copies the whole DLL content and stores it somewhere in its memory?

I've read a little about the PE file format and while that's still a little unclear to me as whole I understand that it has something to do with how a program handle DLLs. Does a DLL get loaded into one of the PE sections as whole, or does the PE format somehow keep pointers to the functions of the DLL that is loaded elsewhere in memory? Or does it do something entirely different that I'm not getting right?

Bonus question if you guys don't mind: Does the PE file format build up the entirety of a program and all the code that runs a program is stored somewhere in the sections, or does the PE file format just take up part of a programs memory while sections and headers contains information to help the program run?

I'm probably horribly misunderstanding a lot of things here, I'm in the process of learning and I do it all for fun. I have tried to do research of my own but I don't always understand perfectly.

Comment: It's very similar to how an EXE file gets loaded, but it gets loaded into a process's address space, not a new empty address space.

Comment: PE format keep pointers to the functions of the DLL  in *IAT* table, DLLs is loaded elsewhere in memory

Answer (score 1):

For all you care, your process has a private copy of the DLL. In practice however, the OS loads the DLL into physical memory *once* and the DLL is memory mapped into each process that needs it. The OS is smart enough to take notes of which pieces of the memory-mapped DLL are written to and allocate process-specific memory for them. (the technical terms here are "page faults" and "copy on write")

As for your other question: the file on disk is interpreted as a PE file in order to ascertain a few things, such as its preferred load address (= the address where the DLL will reside in mapped memory), imports (other DLLs) and entry point. (this function is typically called `DllMain`, which is called when a DLL is loaded/unloaded and when new threads are created/destroyed)

The sections defined in the DLL define which parts of the file are code and which are resources. All are loaded and mapped into memory, but the memory mapping for the code parts are made executable.

There is far more to explain, so take a look at [the Wikipedia article on Dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading), the documentation of [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya), the [Windows documentation on DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/about-dynamic-link-libraries) and [some articles](https://wiki.osdev.org/PE) [about the](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files) [PE file format](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/articles/pefileformat.html)